# How to log bash command with its output?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, logging, command-history

I want the actual **command line** be **logged together** with its **output**.

I routinely execute important commands like this:

```
PERL5LIB=${PERL5LIB}:/something/extra my-command.pl many arguments which I want to save 2>&1 | tee -a my-command.log
```

Now `my-command.log` contains both `stdout` and `stderr` of `my-command.pl`.
However, it does *not* contain the actual *command line* above.

I know of the `bash` history file; so, I guess, I could copy from there (or from the terminal) by hand, but this is not a good solution, of course.

I guess I could write a shell function which would accept a command line, echo it, and then execute it, but then I would have to deal with the quoting hell.

I tried `set -v` but that appears to ignore redirection.

[`script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) does save the command line (but only if I have start a new shell, not with `-c`) but it does *not* work in the emacs shell interaction buffer and it saves the shell prompt too - including the escape sequences! - to its log file, so it is suboptimal.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/script

Comment: @Zoredache: `script` does not save the command line; for my purposes it is no better than `tee -a`.

Comment: script does save the command line AFAIK.  Execute 'script' before you enter your command and it will record the entire session until you hit Ctrl+D.

Comment: @JimG.: I just tried; it contains shell prompts and output from the commands I type, but not the commands themselves

Comment: @sds, that is very odd. It stores everything I type on my system, you must be doing something unusual.  Try using [screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen), and enable log mode?

Comment: @Zoredache: ah yes, it does not work under emacs shell...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `-x` option for bash:

```
bash -x "PERL5LIB=${PERL5LIB}:/something/extra my-command.pl many arguments which I want to save" 2>&1 | tee -a my-command.log
```

My test:

```
$ bash -x -c "echo a bunch of difffernt arguments"
+ echo a bunch of difffernt arguments
a bunch of difffernt arguments
```